# How to optimize queries and remove SQL Injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following query

```
query = {}
if params[:post_id]  
  query.merge!('post_id' => "profiles.post_id = '#{params[:post_id]}'")
end
if params[:name].present?
  query.merge!('name' => "name = '#{params[:name]}'")
end
if params[:gender].present?
  query.merge!('gender' => "gender = '#{params[:gender}' ")
end

ProductPost.includes(:profiles).where("#{query.values.join(' and ') }").references(:profiles)
```

How to optimize above code and how to remove my SQL Injection.
I'm getting SQL Injection on every value of my HASH.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would write something like this:

```
scope = ProductPost.includes(:profiles).references(:profiles)

scope = scope.where(profiles: { post_id: params[:post_id] }) if params[:post_id]
scope = scope.where(name: params[:name])                     if params[:name]
scope = scope.where(gender: params[:gender])                 if params[:gender]

scope
```

Comment: Great answer. ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.where protects the application from SQL injection if you pass in hash values or an array. Not so much if you pass in strings. Additionally each line in that code above returns an ActiveRelation and you can chain on that until you try to use the query to get results.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but What will be the case when ProductPost have thousands of records? - My query takes 0.5 ms. for 1 Lakh Records and I executed your first query and it took 7.0 ms and next onward queries take more time to execute as per the conditions. I have more then 7 if condition.

Comment: You might want to add some indexes to your database columns to improve response time on complex queries.

Comment: I want to execute only 1 query @ end of the conditions.

Comment: My example would run only one query, because this is how chained scopes work in Rails. About performance: Without knowing some queries you want to run and your database schema it is impossible to give advise about improving indexes or if another database technology (like full-text search engines) might be a better solution.